# PayPal IPN Simulator and Sandbox account

Tags: ios, paypal, sandbox, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

Im making an ipn handler for my iOS Application.
Im using classic paypal api with my app.
The thing is when i test from the PayPal IPN Simulator it works fine.
I got the post message below from the simulator (with express checkout i dont remember):

```
map[
business:[seller@paypalsandbox.com] 
item_number1:[AK-1234] 
receiver_id:[seller@paypalsandbox.com] 
first_name:[John] 
mc_shipping1:[1.02] 
tax:[2.02] 
residence_country:[US] 
txn_type:[cart] 
mc_shipping:[3.02] 
test_ipn:[1] 
custom:[xyz123] 
mc_handling:[2.06] 
mc_handling1:[1.67] 
payer_id:[TESTBUYERID01] 
payment_status:[Completed] 
receiver_email:[seller@paypalsandbox.com] 
mc_currency:[USD] 
verify_sign:[AdsvkafFyuBADI8IS081RggbvUxmAu2ntBemAGacZ3Dx56qQzmc9QzhK] 
address_country:[United States] 
item_name1:[something] 
mc_fee:[0.44] 
address_state:[CA] 
mc_gross1:[9.34] 
payer_status:[unverified] 
last_name:[Smith] 
invoice:[abc1234] 
payment_date:[07:44:54 23 May 2013 PDT] 
address_city:[San Jose] 
mc_gross:[12.34] 
address_street:[123, any street] 
notify_version:[2.4] 
txn_id:[298300930] 
payer_email:[buyer@paypalsandbox.com] 
address_status:[confirmed] 
payment_type:[instant] 
address_zip:[95131] 
address_country_code:[US] 
address_name:[John Smith]
]
```

But when i tried to test with a Sandbox account i got the post message below which also works fine:

```
map[
fees_payer:[EACHRECEIVER] 
transaction[0].id:[89799058XE923193M] 
verify_sign:[AE6aVMFpE6M3pfCoNe9gPQ4pMixOA9NNUFbTWPTrOik1CqrdIVxc3K3M] 
pay_key:[AP-9DJ400382D973781B] 
transaction[0].id_for_sender_txn:[8MC20151R46812309] 
transaction[0].status:[Completed] 
action_type:[PAY] 
transaction[0].is_primary_receiver:[false] 
sender.useCredentials:[true] 
transaction[0].pending_reason:[NONE] 
transaction[0].amount:[USD 29.00] 
payment_request_date:[Thu May 23 07:46:49 PDT 2013] 
reverse_all_parallel_payments_on_error:[false] 
test_ipn:[1] 
status:[COMPLETED] 
transaction[0].status_for_sender_txn:[Completed] 
transaction[0].paymentType:[SERVICE] 
notify_version:[UNVERSIONED] 
transaction[0].receiver:[mail-facilitator@something.com] 
return_url:[http://www.paypal.com] 
log_default_shipping_address_in_transaction:[false] 
charset:[windows-1252] 
cancel_url:[http://www.paypal.com] 
transaction_type:[Adaptive Payment PAY] 
ipn_notification_url:[http://something.com/ipnhandler/]
]
```

But as you can see there is no similarity between these two and there isn't anything usefull for me here.
With simulator i got payer name , email etc. but with using a Sandbox account i think i only notify myself that i got a payment.
I wonder why is this happening and is it gonna be like this when the app live.

Comment: So you have no idea?Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but yes, the IPNs that are being sent as a result of adaptive payments are different because the transaction is different. For example, since there can be multiple receivers, having a single receiver_id field wouldn't make sense. Paypal provides an overview of all fields and possible values: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIPN/